# React Native FlatList with other Component doesn't scroll to the end

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I got a page RN flatlist with textbox/button/others component, but the problem is I am not able to scroll till the end of flatlist, there is some other part was kind of overflow.
[image]

```
 <View>
<TextInput
    value={this.state.code}
    onSubmitEditing={this.getPr}
    style={styles.input}
    placeholder="placeholder"
/>
<Button onPress={this.getPr} title="Cari" color="blue" />
<FlatList
    data={this.props.produk}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View key={item.id}>
            <Image
                resizeMode="cover"
                source={{ uri: item.thumb }}
                style={styles.fotoProduk}
            />
        </View>
    )}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
/>
</View>;
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Wrap `Flatlist` with `style={{flex:1}}`. If it does not work add `marginBottom` to flatlist

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>

<FlatList
    data={this.props.produk}
    renderItem={({ item }) =>
        <View key={item.id} >
            <Image resizeMode="cover" source={{ uri: item.thumb }} style={styles.fotoProduk} />
        </View>
    }
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}/>
</View>
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. I was trying to add padding to the top which caused the rest of the content to be pushed down. You need to set the `contentContainerStyle` prop to modify this correctly and then set all the remaining styles on the `style` prop of the `FlatList`. Example:

```js
<FlatList
  style={{
    flex: 1
  }}
  contentContainerStyle={{
    paddingTop: 40
  }}
  data={this.props.produk}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <View key={item.id}>
      <Image
        resizeMode="cover"
        source={{ uri: item.thumb }}
        style={styles.fotoProduk}
      />
    </View>
  )}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Adding **style={{flex:1}}** in View.
2. In FlatList add **contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 10}}**. Check the example code:

   ```
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <FlatList
                contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 10}}
                renderItem={({ item }) =>
                  return(console.log(item))
                }
                />
        </View>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to add **flex:1** to the outer view to fix the issue.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

You can set `width: '100%', height: '100%'` in style of FlatList/ ScrollView to try.

Comment: If you are not 100% sure do not answer like this. You can comment, or you can answer by explaining in detail what you are saying.

Comment: Cauz as i know that ScrollView/ FlatList sometime missing height when using vertical scroll(i didn't try in horizontal mode). Btw, sorry for my Endrisk :D